# Mobile Device Management with iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios4, mdm

Can any one provide me some information regarding iphone Device Management with iOS4.

1) How to implement it with & how this will works.

2) Can it work with only Enterprise licensee or can we implement it simply Developer License.

3) Any specific documentation or help.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

1.) How to implement it with & how this will works. 
Check http://www.apple.com/iphone/business/integration/ especially iPhone_MDM.pdf.  if I can summary it, it is 
"Apple added management function(MDM) which connect to APNS with configured MDM app-id, if there are any APNS notification wait for the device, it connect to configured MDM server via HTTPS and process any management work configured"

2.) Can it will work with only Enterprise licensee or can we implement it simply Developer License. 
"Based on documentation it works with Enterprise license only but it looks currently open to developer license also"

3.) Any specific documentation or help.
I find couple of company implemented it(Mobileiron, Airwatch, Sybase etcs), but I didn't find detail HTTPS request and response spec yet. For MDM configuration part, you can use iPhone Configuration Utility.(ipcu). I know it is working as I am using one of implemented products.