# iOS 4 with MDM features how to implement it?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, mdm, payload

Can any one help me to give me some answers on the below mention 
Queries:

(i) Do we need to enroll for Enterprise Developer Program to
implement MDM for iOS4.0. We also have some client agent . But I found
some applications like "MobileIron" in AppStore which provides the MDM
service.

(ii) I have used the iPhone Configuration utility and tried to
install the MDM payloads, it gives out error in installation. So i
tried hosting the file in the secure web server and hit the link in
the safari browser, but it gives out a error like "Safari Could not
install the profile due to unknown error".

(iii) I have checked and couldn't find any information on pushing the
Configuration profile from server to device through Push Notification.
But in your blog under iPhone MDM topic , it has been mentioned that
through push notification service, remote commands and querying the
device is possible. So can you give any format that we have to follow
in order to push the configuration profiles to the device so that the
MDM service running in the background does the rest without user
intervention.

I am looking forward to hear from any one and I will be highly obliged if
anyone can guide me with answers for the above.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mobile Device Management with iphone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4066651/mobile-device-management-with-iphone)

Comment: If you need to clarify your earlier question, edit that.  Don't repeat questions.

Answer (score 3):

I can hopefully answer your questions.

i) Can you use the MDM features without an APNS Certificate (Joining the Apple Developer Program)? 
   Ron>> No, unfortunately to use the MDM features of any MDM Vendor you need an APNS certificate.  However you only need the Enterprise one if you want to push down your own applications (applications signed with your certificate).  If you just want to manage policies on the device you can use the standard APNS certificate ($99 vs $299).

ii) Once you have your APNS certifiacte you can use products like MobiControl (www.soti.net) to deploy policies that would be in the iPhone Configuration Utility.

iii) Again with products like MobiControl this can be done silently.  MobiControl just released their software and the big advantage is that it's relatively low cost (about $660USD for 10 devices for life) and there is no re-occuring costs unlike Mobile Iron etc...

Best of Luck!